# There is no `$ rootScope` in` Angular9`. What can be used?

Tags: angular9

In `AngularJS` i used`$ rootScope` to pass user data, for example:

```
$ rootScope.user = {
id: '4',
username: 'user'
...
};
$ rootScope.user.authenticated = false;
```

the data in `$ rootScope` was filled in every time a page was opened or updated using a query to`SQL`.

In `Angular 9` i did not find the use of`$ rootScope`.
Tell me, where can such data be stored in `Angular 9` and with what help can this functionality be implemented?

Answer (score 4):

In angular, if you need anything like that, you create a service, provide it in root and inject it wherever you want it. For example:

### The service:

```js
// Create the service (providedIn: 'root') makes it available globally
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserService {
  user: any ={
    id: '4',
    username: 'user'
    ...
  };
}
```

### Using the service in a component:

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  _isAuthenticated: boolean;

  // Inject the service
  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Using the service
    this._isAuthenticated = _useService.user?.authenticated ?? false;
  }
}
```

PS: The code above uses two [interesting typescript features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) (which are new as I write this answer): optional chaining and Nullish Coalescing. You can always use a regular ternary operator instead of that:

```js
this._isAuthenticated = _useService.user ? _useService.user?.authenticated : false
```

Comment: Thanks. Tell me, how to make it global, not for a specific component?

Comment: It *is global* but in angular style. By that I mean services provided in root are the angular way of doing something global and you can just inject them wherever you need them. Is there any specific scenario where this approach doesn't fit your design?

Comment: So far only interested in such a possibility

Comment: In, fact, you can provide more than just services. You can also provide values, as long as you build a token for it. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#non-class-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

When my team and I migrated one of the projects from AngularJS to Angular, I took a look at when $rootScope was being used in the old app and it turns out it was used for identity/authentication 95% of the time.  A few other use cases were regarding the spinner, browser related settings and edge cases.

It seems like your use case is similar to ours as well.  I just folded that $rootScope.user into an existing AngularJS service called identity (or it could be auth, or whatever).  So in each component that referred to that $rootScope.user, I replaced it with the following. The constructor is just dependency injection, allows you to use the variables within the identity service anywhere.

whatever.component.ts

```
currentUser = this.identity.currentUser
constructor(private identity: IdentityService) {}
```

The identity service looks something like the below.  There's a getter function for the current user, and when it's not available, you look into the cookie, or otherwise, it's blank object (unauthenticated).

identity.service.ts

```
private _currentUser;  //should only obtain currentUser via get currentuser()

constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

get currentUser() {
    if (!this._currentUser) {
      this._currentUser = this.getUserFromCookie() || {};  //get from cookie
    }
    return this._currentUser;
  }

getUserFromCookie() {
    return this.cookieService.get('currentUser') ? JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('currentUser')) : {};
  }
```

Hopefully this gets you started and helps others as well.